# ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues not showing Dates

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I have a worksheet "Tracker" with 36 Scatter graphs. The same worksheet contains 12 sets of data, each set containing 3 variables that need to be graphed wrt to the associated date/time. I've named them in such a way that creating a loop is possible to make the code cleaner.

Here's the problem: This works great but the Horizontal Axes of all the charts are not representing the actual values. `={"1/10/2017  12:11:03 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:06 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:09 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:12 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:15 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:19 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:22 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:25 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:28 PM","1/10/2017  12:11:31 PM"}`

Above is what the XValues series shows when you go to Select Data, but the chart shows 1/0/00, 1/1/00, 1/2/00, and so for the X values.. I made sure that the date columns are formatted with a date/time format.
Here's the code:

```
    For i = 1 To 12
    k = (i * 4) + 49
    RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker").Cells(1, k).Offset(Sheets("Tracker").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Location" & i & "_1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets("Tracker").Cells(1, k + 2).Value
    **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(RowCount, k)).Value**
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k + 2), Cells(RowCount, k + 2)).Value
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = Worksheets("Tracker").Cells(1, k + 3).Value
    **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(RowCount, k)).Value**
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k + 3), Cells(RowCount, k + 3)).Value

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Location" & i & "_2").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets("Tracker").Cells(1, k + 1).Value
    **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(RowCount, k)).Value**
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, k + 1), Cells(RowCount, k + 2)).Value

    l = (i * 2) + 102
    RowCount1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker").Cells(1, l).Offset(Sheets("Tracker").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Location" & i & "_3").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets("Tracker").Cells(1, l + 1).Value
    **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, l), Cells(RowCount1, l)).Value**
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(2, l + 1), Cells(RowCount1, l + 2)).Value

    Next i
```

When I hover over the data points on the graph, the date shows in the text, but it seems like it is plotting the Y value with numbers starting at 1 and not utlizing the date/time at all.

In the past, I've just written each graph out with the associated series, but since there are 36 graphs, I don;t want to have to do this for each - that's crazy.
Using this I have no issues:

```
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AC$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AA$1:$AA$" & RowCount1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AC$1:$AC$" & RowCount1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AD$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AA$1:$AA$" & RowCount1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AD$1:$AD$" & RowCount1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you should try setting your `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Location" & i & "_1")` object to a `ChartObject`, and there is no need to use `Activate` to modify the chart.

You could loop thourgh all `SeriesCollection` in your `ChartObject`, by using `For j= 1 To .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoChartTest()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As SeriesCollection
Dim SerRng  As Range
Dim j As Long, i As Long, RowCount1 As Long

' set the chart object
Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Location" & i & "_1")

With ChtObj '<-- modify properties of the chart object (without Activating it)
    For j = 1 To .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count ' <-- loop through all series collections
        Set SerRng = Range("AC1").Offset(, j - 1)

        .Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Name = "=" & "Location" & i & "!" & SerRng.Address
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(j).XValues = "=" & "Location" & i & "!$AA$1:$AA$" & RowCount1
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = "=" & "Location" & i & "!" & SerRng.Address & ":$AC$" & RowCount1
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the reply. I should've have added the fact that the date/time is not only in Column AA but in every fifth column starting from AA. Can a similiar SerRng be used to define the different date/tiem columns or will this also show up as a number or incorrect date/time? This is very clean though, I've picked a few very helpful pointers here.

Comment: @jmeddy if you could edit your post, share  a sample fo your chart, and where is the data taken from, I think I could understand better what you mean and trying to achieve